# Use react's testutils with jquery elements

Tags: jquery, reactjs, simulate, reactjs-testutils

I am trying to test a react page. Using `.trigger("input", {which: 65})` doesn't seem to invoke the SyntheticEvent. So I was wondering if was possible to combine jQuery and `.simulate` of the testUtils somehow?

Basically, i am trying to do something like

```
$('selector').simulate('input', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot. Using TestUtils you operate with virtual dom - therefore you cannot use jquery.

You can check this [tutorial](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/approaches-to-testing-react-components-an-overview/) for more info on the options you have for testing react apps.